# Do context diagrams have cardinalities?

Tags: diagrams, model, modeling

Can someone explain if the context diagrams(as used in requirements engineering) have cardinalities(as defined in UML diagrams)?

What I want to ask is, are cardinalities part of a context diagram's syntax?

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable.  Can you edit your question to make it more specific, or provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: I made an edit, hope it helps a little bit to clarify my question.

Comment: I know what cardinality is, I just don't understand why you're asking if a context diagram has it.  Does this help?:  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/NDE_Context_Diagram_%28vector%29.svg

Comment: This was part of a Right/Wrong question and I am trying to understand if it makes sense to include a cardinality in a context diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the system analysis methods have in common the idea that a system has boundaries with the environment that surrounds it and with which it interacts.

The term "context diagram" is used to represent this initial high level view, before decomposing the system and the flows into its (more detailed) parts.  Modeling methods such as IDEF0 (formerly SADT), or DFD (e.g. Yourdon's or Gane's & Sarson'ts) and others used to have such level 0 charts.

As these context diagrams are the start of the analysis, cardinality is generally not yet known, and generally not usefull at this level.  And anyway, functional analysis diagramology such as IDEF0 don't even know cardinality.

In UML there's [no formal context diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23761522/3723423) defined. There are several type of diagrams which could represent the system in its context, but the most suitable and which also shows the full context is the top level use case diagram, which shows the system under consideration and the actors/systems in the environments with which the system interacts.  On such a high level diagram there would be no cardinality.

I would therefore suggest **NO** as answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear and detailed answer. This solved my question and gave me a better understanding.